# How to deserialize number value in Firestore field and read this inside de while/loop using kotlinx.coroutines

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

In the firestore I created a field named PararUm, type number (it does not have Int, when I enter it manually) and I put value 1.

The problem is that the return has been PararUm(PararUm=1) and not just 1.
(99-below)

**When I resolved this, I would have solved the first part of the project.**

Regarding the second, I want to use kotlinx.coroutines to work within a while/loop (which queries the value of the PararUm field) in a synchronous, non-asynchronous way (as firebase requires)

Can I do something like???(999-below):

I threw this topic down, but I was not happy[1](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1248#issuecomment-501039088).

### 99-below:

### model

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class PararUm(
        var PararUm: Int? = 0
)
```

### Activity

```
var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     var pararumRef = 
db.collection("smartmodel").document("xxxxxxxxxxxx")

    pararumRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
        var PararUm = documentSnapshot.toObject(PararUm::class.java)
        Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "1999 1999 1999" + PararUm)

    }
}
```

### 999-below:

```
while (!FCMotorUmA.value) {

    var snapshot = pararumRef.get().await()
        
    var pararum = snapshot.toObject(PararUM::class.java)

    if (pararum.equals(0)) {

        // Do something 1


    } else if (pararum.equals(1)) {

        // Do something 2
    }

}
```

Comment: anyone? This is a perfectly adequate beginner question :)

Comment: Sadly, it isn't a clear question."The problem is that the return has been PararUm(PararUm=1) and not just 1. (99-below)": it seems like you're reading it into a class and expecting an int, of course you'll have a class instance.

Comment: @Gazihan Alankus, 
What would you have to say about the second part of the question?

Comment: the answer to the first question is:

 var PararUm = documentSnapshot.toObject(PararUm::class.java)?.PararUm

and take the word data, from the class PararUm.